# How to set a Jquery function on timeout?

Tags: jquery, function, timeout

I have found how to set functions on timeout . But its not working in this JQUERY function .Please help me . Here goes the jquery codes :

```
$(function() {          
            var $wrapper= $( '#fc-wrapper' ),
                $handle = $wrapper.children( 'div.fc-handle-pull' );                

            $(function( event ) {               
                ( $handle.data( 'opened' ) ) ? close() : open();                
            } );

            $wrapper.hammer().bind( 'dragend', function( event ) {
                switch( event.direction ) {
                    case 'right': open(); break;
                    case 'left': close(); break;
                }
            });

            function open() {
                $wrapper.addClass( 'fc-wrapper-open' );
                $handle.data( 'opened', true );
            }

            function close() {
                $wrapper.removeClass( 'fc-wrapper-open' );
                $handle.data( 'opened', false );
                }

        } );
```

Please tell me how to set this function on timeout . Thanks in advance

Comment: could you show us your attempts?

Comment: `$(function( event ) {               
                ( $handle.data` makes no sense to have the jQuery wrapping it.

Comment: What do you wan to timeout???

Comment: It is using a jquery plugin called hammer.js . So it makes sense . I just want to know to set the whole stuff on a timeout . Thanks

Comment: I think that you should provide more information. Any links or screenshot?

Comment: Thanks vixid and epascarello . Problem solved . 8|

Comment: @M.Rashid glad you were able to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem myself . Here is the codes :

```
setTimeout( function(){ 

            var $wrapper= $( '#fc-wrapper' ),
                $handle = $wrapper.children( 'div.fc-handle-pull' );                

            $(function( event ) {               
                ( $handle.data( 'opened' ) ) ? close() : open();                
            } );

            $wrapper.hammer().bind( 'dragend', function( event ) {
                switch( event.direction ) {
                    case 'right': open(); break;
                    case 'left': close(); break;
                }
            });

            function open() {
                $wrapper.addClass( 'fc-wrapper-open' );
                $handle.data( 'opened', true );
            }

            function close() {
                $wrapper.removeClass( 'fc-wrapper-open' );
                $handle.data( 'opened', false );
                }


        }  , 2000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want this to execute after a timeout, just wrap the code in `setTimeout`:

```
$(function() {
  // call setTimeout with a function and a timeout length in milliseconds
  var waitLength = 1000; // ms
  var timer = setTimeout(function () {

        var $wrapper= $( '#fc-wrapper' ),
            $handle = $wrapper.children( 'div.fc-handle-pull' );                

        // no need to wrap this in $(function(){...}) since you already
        // did that on line 1
        $handle.data( 'opened' ) ? close() : open();

        $wrapper.hammer().bind( 'dragend', function( event ) {
            switch( event.direction ) {
                case 'right': open(); break;
                case 'left': close(); break;
            }
        });

        function open() {
            $wrapper.addClass( 'fc-wrapper-open' );
            $handle.data( 'opened', true );
        }

        function close() {
            $wrapper.removeClass( 'fc-wrapper-open' );
            $handle.data( 'opened', false );
        }

  }, waitLength); // end setTimeout call

});
```